# iOS Dropbox Datastore Crash after App Resumes

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I listen for when my app resumes working (the user comes back to the app) and I fire a sync when this happens:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  NSLog(@"App resumed...");
  //Fire a sync
  [[PPDropbox shared] sync];
}
```

I've had a few crash reports that happen after this event and an attempt to sync that says:

```
Fatal Exception: DBException
DBException: SHUTDOWN: sqlite_util.cpp:208: SqliteConnectionBase has been closed {-[DBDatastore sync:]}
```

My `sync` method currently looks like this:

```
-(void)sync
{
  if(self.datastore){
    [self.datastore sync:nil];
  }
}
```

Is there some kind of check I should be doing when I sync to ensure the SQLite connection is still available?

*Dropbox Datastore version 3.1.1, iOS 8.1*

Comment: When does your app shut down the DBDatastoreManager? Is it possible it was shut down when the app tried to call sync? If so, that can cause this. (Also, possibly if the DBDatastore was closed.) This error message isn't very clear, unfortunately, but there may be more information in the log, e.g., following "Terminating app due to...". Do you have that part?

Comment: I close the datastore in `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`. Should I be closing it in something else? Here's the full crash log: http://d.pr/n/DV26

Comment: I think applicationWillTerminate should be fine, but what about the DBDatastoreManager? Do/when do you shut that down? I'm asking because I know this error can occur when attempting to sync a datastore from a DBDatastore from a DBDatastoreManager that has been shut down. Unfortunately the stack trace doesn't provide much more information. Have you been able to reproduce this?

Comment: I don't shut the `DBDatastoreManager` down anywhere. Should I also do that in `applicationWillTerminate`?

Comment: I can't been able to reproduce it yet, no. I'm just seeing crash logs from my app's users.

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly shut down DBDatastoreManager, but calling sync on a DBDatastore for a DBDatastoreManager that was shut down is the only way I know how to trigger this error. Is it maybe going out of scope in some cases? If you can reproduce it though please let us know.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this same problem in my application.
My scenario is like this: I unlink the account and shutdown the datastore.
Then I try to link dropbox one more time.

My singleton instance tries the sync in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url` method, then it crashes with the same error mentioned in the question.

My problem is the datastore has been shutdown when I try to sync(I set the datastore only when singleton was init).

So what I did was just set the datastore before calling that sync, for instance

`self.datastore = [[DBDatastoreManager sharedManager] openDefaultDatastore:nil];`

Comment: Are there any issues running `openDefaultDatastore` if the datastore is already open? Or will it just ignore it if it's already open? I ask because I want to try your solution, but I don't want to introduce a new problem of re-opening an open datastore.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum I used the above method in my application and login/logout a lot of times and did not see anything suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that your problem is not really that you've lost your connection to SQLite, rather that there is some other problem that corrupts the memory that uses SQLLite.

How sophisticated are you at testing and debugging?  Try doing stuff like enabling Guard Malloc, and use assert to validate the parameters to your methods (if you have a pointer is it permitted to be NULL?).

My article on assertions might help: [assert() is the Documentation that Keeps on Testing](http://www.warplife.com/tips/code/quality/test/assertion/)